# Where should I ask beginner-level server questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, serverfault

I have a lot of server related questions but I don't know where to ask them. The most obvious place, [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com/) seems to be for people who are already experts in the field (evident from the knowledge level in the responses, and the FAQ section:

> and it is not about...Networking outside the professional workplace

Where should I ask these? Ask Ubuntu, Stack Overflow, or Super User?

Comment: what kind of "beginner server questions"?

Comment: @Sathya things which are more complicated than anything on a tutorial. ie. username/passwords, should they be stored in a SQL table? Is that secure enough? What about databsing pictures? Where should the actual files be stored? A novice programmer wouldn't know that server-side you log in as user `www-data` and this restricts where you can save files

Comment: A question about password storage prbably belongs on security.

Comment: @Zoredache the FAQ section reads 'IT Security - Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals'. I don't feel comfortable asking them where I should save my username/password.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, on Server Fault the level of ability is not as important as the role of the server/network and your level of responsibility for it.  Generally, we expect you to have root/admin access.  The question should not be about things only serving your home.

There are already questions that cover most of what you mentioned in your comments – though some aspects of those questions are also covered on the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site.

Honestly, I think you should just take the time to write a good, clear, non-subjective question.  Pick the site that looks like the best fit to you.  If a good question is asked on the wrong site, it will probably get migrated to the best site and get answers.  Having a question you ask get migrated is not a bad thing.

Comment: 100x this, it's not about being a beginner - we where all there once.